# Using Markov's Inequality to find maximum number of entries greater than 5o

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A list consists of 1000 non-negative numbers. The sum of the entries is 9000 and the sum of the squares of the entries of 91000. Let $X$ represent an entry picked at random from the list. I am asked to find the mean of $X$, the mean of $X^2$, and the variance of $X$. Then, using Markov’s inequality, I am to show that the number of entries in the list greater than or equal to 50 is at most 180.

I have calculated $E(X)$=9

$E(X^2)$=91

$Var(X)$=9

And using Markov's inequality I have reasoned that $P(X\ge50)\le0.18$

The step from here to there being less than 180 entries less than 50 is unclear to me though -  I see that $1,000*0.18=180$ but I'm not definite as to why that give us an upper bound on the number of entries greater than or equal to 50.

I am then asked to find the corresponding bound from applying Markov's inequality to $X^2$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:
https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~stark/SticiGui/Text/location.htm.
By the way, the variance euqals to ten :)